# Is there a way to make GIT follow renamed files through history

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have committed some files to the GIT repository. When I was submitting different versions of the same file, a few files had different names. 
I submitted files like `Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py` in initial commit and remained the same for 3 more commits file renamed to `Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py` in the next version and remained the same till last commit. When I reached the version where file `Task_1.5 changed to Task_2.2`, I tried the following command

```
git rm Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
git add Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
```

I got the response

```
renamed Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py ->Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
```

when I try the command

```
git log -- Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
```

Git follows `Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py` from final commit till the commit where file was renamed, and there is the SHA code. The following is the last message of the log of `Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py`

```
$ git log -- Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
...
commit 321a3e71034f37485f0f10a7fe676de12f14c8d6
Author: 
Date:   
    Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py 2016_2
    Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py renamed to Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py Scripts_2016_2
    Deleted Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py 2016_1
```

when I try the command

```
git log -- Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
```

It follows from the file renamed, with the same SHA Code till the initial commit. Following is the first line of log message

```
$ git log -- Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
commit 321a3e71034f37485f0f10a7fe676de12f14c8d6
Author: 
Date:  
    Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py 2016_2
    Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py renamed to Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py Scripts_2016_2
    Deleted Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py 2016_1
...
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I try the command

```
$ git log -- Task_2.2_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py
```

git should follow it to the initial commit of `Task_1.5_FinalSuburbsProcessing.py`

There are few more cases where file name has changed in their subsequent versions, I did the same thing for them and git log follows them till the initial commit.

But in some cases, git log stops at the file delete rename commit and then continues from there. Just as in this case, both commits have the same SHA codes. I have even checked the SHA Codes of the commits and found that their is parent-child relation in subsequent commits and yet git log stops at rename.
Is there a way to force git to follow the `Task_2.2` from last commit to `Task_1.5` Initial Commit.

Comment: `git log --follow` will follow *one* file, to some extent: you tell it "tell me about commits in which file X is different in parent and child" and `--follow` checks to see if there are commits in which, in the parent, file X has some earlier name W and starts looking for commits in which file W is different in parent and child and telling you about those. Then, if some earlier commit implies a rename from V to W, `git log` begins looking at the file named V from here earlier, and so on.